# Image carousel or gallery in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, webpack, mime, css-loader

I am trying to use webpack to compile an exsiting React Native project to make it available on Web platform. There is a package named react-native-snap-carousel that doesn't work well on web platform.

I used a if statement to make it use another package (react-image-gallery) when it's on web, after doing that, it works well on Web now, but when I try to open it on ios or android, there prompt an error, the message is something like "Unable to resolve "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css" from "FlashGalleryWeb.js". Since the css file is part of the react-image-gallery package, removal will make things look weird in the browser, I need to find another way to solve it.

I tried to inject the css style at run time by creating a new file, then invoke it conditionally.
Firstly, copy and paste the css file to the screens folder, to make it easy to find.
Then create a new file WebCSSLoader.js, and the code in it is

```
export function loadWebCSS() {
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = '../path/to/image-gallery.css';
  document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Then in my FlashGalleryWeb.js file, add the following code:

```
import { loadWebCSS } from './WebCSSLoader';

function MyComponent() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    loadWebCSS();
  }

  // Rest of my code
}
```

Now, I can open it on ios and android platform, but the CSS style won't be applied on Web. The error message in console is: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/screens/image-gallery.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Additionally, here is part of the webpack.config.js:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
```

Is there any ways to solve these problems? I'm open to any approach, including using other packages or make any changes on my code.

Thanks in advance!